# Github - Failed to clone/remote sync or clone or any github activity

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I have github on Windows-7. The github doesn't seem to allow me to check in code as something is messed up.

I did try changing the credentials & so forth by looking up online but nothing seems to work.
I still see the `Bad credentials` error alongside some `wamp developer` errors.
I don't know how `wamp developer` is related to GitHub.

I did have WAMP developer once upon a time on the PC.
The log file for the attempt is here: [Github log file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xka55xcla5ziz5m/github.log?dl=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error:

```
2016-03-22 12:44:50.7329|
ERROR|thread: 5|StartupLogging| MISSING PATH!!: 'C:\WampDeveloper\Components\Apache\bin'
```

That simply means your %PATH% currently reference one non-existent path: you could clean-up your environment variable PATH which is currently quite large.

This is not-blocking for GitHub Desktop though.

---

The other error is linked to a key previously used for:

```
Logged user r... off of host 'https://<server_url>'
```

When that key "`C:\Users\ffgr.ghjk\.ssh\github_rsa`" is used to authenticate to `github.com` does not work.
Make sure that key (the public one `github_rsa.pub`) is added to your GitHub account: "[Adding a new SSH key to your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/)"

Comment: Thanks VonC. Appreciate your time. I'l give this a go.

Comment: @usert4jju7 I have already accepted your edit, one minute ago :)